# How to apply custom function in aggregate R

Tags: r, na

everyone!
I have tried to find similar question, but i didn't. Let's assume that we have a simple data frame like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm4jv.png)

I need to aggregate by group: `aggregate(value~group, data=data, mean,na.rm=TRUE)`
But, when i use `na.rm=TRUE`, group 1 disappears. It is absolutely necessary to use `na.rm=TRUE`, because in opposite case i will get incorrect averages. I also have tried to use custom function:

```
customMean<-function(x){
  if (all(is.na(x))){
      return (NA_integer_)
  } else {  
    return(mean(x,na.rm=TRUE))
  }
}
```

but, the result is same. Does anybody know how to fix this issue? I expect that final result will be like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMnTt.png) .
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the formula method of `aggregate` has `na.action=na.omit`.  So, it removes the entire row if there is an `NA` value.  We can change it to `na.action=NULL` and it should work.

```
aggregate(value~group, data=data, mean,na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
#    group value
#1     1   NaN
#2     2   2.5
```

Comment: How about `aggregate(data[, 2], list(data$group), mean)`

Comment: @RonakShah It should work.  The formula method has this setting.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2545517 No problem.  Glad to help you.